Why is Apple pushing the "jpeg" file extension?
Using MacOS Sonoma 14.5, when I save a jpg file, MacOS now asks me if I want to save it with the extension ".jpeg" instead of the shorter ".jpg".
Why is Apple pushing a longer extension name for something that has existed for decades?  What benefits are there to using ".jpeg"?

JPEG is the acronym for the Joint Photographic Experts Group, the name of the ISO subcommittee who helped create the standard in 1992.
JPG was required by Windows as it was limited to an 8-3 naming format on FAT file systems prior to Windows 95.

Very good! +1  Your sparsely worded answer is perfect :)

Did the standard call for ".jpeg" in 1992, even though Windows couldn't do it?
